# Helly vs Strong p-Helly Property of Hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraph

I am not clear about the difference between Helly and Strong p-Helly property. For example hypergraph 
H(V, E), V = { 1,2,3 } and E = {(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)}
has non-empty set for each pair of intersection, which makes it qualify as Helly (but not strong p-Helly) however, this triangle hypergraph is not considered as Helly hypergraph. Any insight and correction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your definitions of "Helly property" and "strong Helly property"? My understanding is that a graph has the Helly property if any pairwise intersecting family of edges has nonempty intersection, which would exclude the triangle graph you have defined.

Comment: Your understanding Helly is completely right. But I am afraid, I don't really understand how traingle graph is excluded. It has non-empty intersection set for all pair of edges.

Comment: Strong Helly definition: A hypergraph H is strong p-Helly if for every partial hypergraph(H′) of H, there exist p or less hyperedges in H′ whose core equals the core of H′.

Comment: The family $E$ of edges satisfies the assumptions of the definition: every pair has nonempty intersection; but it doesn't satisfy the conclusion: the intersection of all three edges in the family is empty.

Comment: Yes understood, Thanks :) It would be great if you shed some light over the actual difference of Helly and Strong p-Helly, and it's intuition behind.

Comment: It would still be helpful to edit your question with precise definitions of "p-Helly" and "strong p-Helly", or a link to  complete definitions (e.g., what is a "partial hypergraph" and a "core"?). Based on my understanding, a simple example of a hypergraph that is Helly but not strong Helly is something like $H=(V,E)$ where $V=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $E=\{(a,b,c), (a,c,d), (a,b,d)\}$. Then $E$ has nontrivial intersection (so I guess this means $H$ is $4$-Helly?). But the partial hypergraph induced on $\{b,c,d\}$ is a triangle, hence not $2$-Helly. So $H$ is not strong $2$-Helly.